# skimage regionprops_table extra_properties multichannel relationship between channels example

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have multichannel microscopy images and would like to use the skimage regionprops_table function with extra_properties that calculate relationships between different channels.

E.g. I have a 2 channel image and for every segmented element I want to measure the correlation, euclidean distance and others.

So rather than calculating the same property for every region in all channels I want to calculate a relationship between the channels at every region. Therefore I expect a single column as a result also.

Example:

```
from skimage import measure, segmentation                                      
from skimage import data     
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
coffee = data.coffee()                                             
labels = segmentation.slic(coffee, start_label=1) 

def euclidean_distance(regionmask, intensity_image):
    dist = np.linalg.norm(intensity_image[regionmask])
    return dist

props = regionprops_table(labels,intensity_image=coffee, extra_properties=(euclidean_distance,))
```

The code runs but it doesn't compute the difference between channels. Instead it calculates a euclidean distance within every region for the two channels separately.

Instead I want to have something like this:

```
def euclidean_distance2(regionmask, intensity_image):
    dist = np.linalg.norm(intensity_image[regionmask][...,0].flatten()-    intensity_image[regionmask][...,1].flatten())
    return dist
```

This should calculate the distance between the two channels in every region. But this doesn't work.

```
props = regionprops_table(labels,intensity_image=coffee, extra_properties=(euclidean_distance2,))
>IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

I hope I am making this clear. Let me know if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are after but I'm not clear on why you don't want to want to just run regionprops_table on the separate channels and then calculate the distance between objects? It seems like you're not saving on speed or memory usage by using extra_properties parameter but maybe I'm missing something.